# how get value on selectbox add dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to make a dynamic select box one depends on the other, however I want to add several dynamically and pick up the individual values ​​to be able to select the other one. I tried to do it using the change but it only takes the first select, I wanted to get the value of the selected select and set the other select. Thank you for your help

```js
$(function() {
  var listaPecas = [{
      "Tipo_PecaID": 1,
      "Descricao": "impressora"
    },
    {
      "Tipo_PecaID": 2,
      "Descricao": "teclado"
    },
    {
      "Tipo_PecaID": 3,
      "Descricao": "notebook"
    },
  ];
  var listaModelos = [{
      "id_peca_modelo": 1,
      "Tipo_PecaID": "1",
      "ds_descricao": "epson"
    },
    {
      "id_peca_modelo": 2,
      "Tipo_PecaID": "2",
      "ds_descricao": "asus"
    },
    {
      "id_peca_modelo": 3,
      "Tipo_PecaID": "3",
      "ds_descricao": "microsoft"
    },
  ];


  $(document).on('change', '.peca', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selectpicker.form-control.peca').each(function() {
      id = $(this).val();
      $.each(listaModelos, function(indexInArray, modelo) {
        option = "";
        if (id == modelo.Tipo_PecaID) {
          option = '<option value="' + modelo.id_peca_modelo + '">' + modelo.ds_descricao + '</option>'
        }
      });

      $('.selectpicker.form-control.model').append(option);
      $('.selectpicker.form-control.model').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
  })
});

function adicionarPeca(listaPecas) {
  div = '<div class="row seletor-select">';
  div += '<div class="col-md-3">';
  div += '<select class="selectpicker form-control peca" name="peca" data-live-search="true">';
  $.each(listaPecas, function(indexInArray, peca) {
    div += '<option value="' + peca.Tipo_PecaID + '">' + peca.Descricao + '</option>'
  });
  div += '</select>';
  div += '</div>';
  div += '<div class="col-md-3">';
  div += '<select class="selectpicker form-control model" name="model" data-live-search="true">';
  div += '</select>';
  div += '</div>';
  div += '<div class="col-md-2">';
  div += '<div class="form-group">';
  div += '<input type="text" name="porta" class="form-control" value="">';
  div += '</div>';
  div += '</div>';
  div += '<div class="col-md-1">';
  div += '<div class="form-group">';
  div += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger RemoveLinha">-</button>';
  div += '</div>';
  div += '</div>';
  $("#lista.row").append(div);
  div += '</div>';
  $("#lista").append(div);

  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lista"></div>
```

Comment: You never call `adicionarPeca()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting `option = ""` each time through the `$.each` loop. Unless the selected option matches the last element in `listaModelos`, you won't get the `<option>` value that you want.

You should should initialize the variable before the loop. Also, you should terminate the loop when you find the selected option, since there's no point in continuing to search for it. You can terminate the `$.each` loop by returning `false` from the callback function.

```
  var option = "";
  $.each(listaModelos, function(indexInArray, modelo) {
    if (id == modelo.Tipo_PecaID) {
      option = '<option value="' + modelo.id_peca_modelo + '">' + modelo.ds_descricao + '</option>';
      return false;
    }
  });
```

The next problem is this code:

```
  $('.selectpicker.form-control.model').append(option);
  $('.selectpicker.form-control.model').selectpicker('refresh');
```

This appends the option to *all* the `.model` selectpickers, not just the one after the current `.peca`. Change that to:

```
$(this).closest(".row").find(".selectpicker.form-control.model")
    .append(option)
    .selectpicker('refresh');
```

You also need to use `e.stopPropagation()` in the `change` event handler. The bootstrap-select plugin copies the `peca` class from the `<select>` to the `<div>` wrapper that it adds, so the event bubbles out to the DIV, but `$(this).val()` doesn't work there.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qk5ruay4/14/)

Comment: thanks for the help then but I'm still not getting it, do I have an option to insert more selects only it does not arrow the others only the first one. follow the example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nb3r85up/)

Comment: I've updated the answer and added my changes to your fiddle.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, with these modifications are selecting correctly.